# Selenium (argument --headless) + (marionette = False)

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller

I'm trying to scrap pages with javascript using python. I'm a total beginner at this so I've read lots of tutorials. I've finally found that I needed selenium, beautiful_soup, and the firefox webdriver. So I've done a function (I'm adding the relevant modules too).

```
import bs4
import requests
from urllib.request import Request
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

def page_souping_js(url):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    complete_page = driver.page_source
    driver.close()
    page_soup = soup(complete_page,"html.parser")
    return page_soup
```

which seemed to work fine until I tried to make a .exe file with it (using pyinstaller) and run it on another computer (It works fine on my computer) where I've got this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException : Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

So I've read once again on the subject and "fixed" my code :

```
def page_souping_js(url):
    cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
    cap["marionette"] = False
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap, firefox_options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    complete_page = driver.page_source
    driver.close()
    page_soup = soup(complete_page,"html.parser")
    return page_soup
```

since I've made that change, though, the browser opens, even if I've added the argument "--headless". 
1. Are these two, capabilities and firefox_options, incompatible?
2. if I need set "marionette" to False is there a way to execute this function without the browser opening? Or is there another around this problem?

Hopefully someone'll have an answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok apparently this problem is caused by the fact that the user had a very outdated version of firefox on his machine. The capabilities do not have to be set to anything that isn't default, but the browser should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak about the compatibility of capabilites and firefox_options, but I've had some success with this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def page_souping_js(url):
    options = Options()
    options.set_headless(True)
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    complete_page = driver.page_source
    driver.close()
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(complete_page, "lxml")
    return page_soup
```

This should return the source html without opening the browser. Putting this through PyInstaller didn't seem to cause any issues either.

Side note, the official import statement for BeautifulSoup (according to the [official documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup)) is `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: It still opens up a browser when used with capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using this path to firefox.exe file inside "App" folder. 'path\to\FirefoxPortable\App\Firefox\firefox.exe'

for 64-bit version use this path:
'path\to\FirefoxPortable\App\Firefox64\firefox.exe'